# How long do conflict zones/civil wars last?

Tags: elite-dangerous

In Elite: Dangerous you sometimes find systems that are in a state of civil war. There are multiple conflict zones across the system that are tremendous fun, always on dogfights.

However this seems to pass and you come back to a quiet system.

How long does this state last?

Is there anything players can do to resolve it, one way or the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Civil war lasts until one of the factions wins. In order to resolve it, accept (and complete) combat zone missions for one minor faction, until they win. Just entering the conflict zone and taking a side (earning combat bonds) doesn't help as much (or at all?).

Civil war happens when a minor faction gets enough influence to compete with another minor faction. The winner gets control of a station. You can create civil war by running missions for a faction that doesn't control a station, until their influence gets high enough. You can't create civil war if there was one between those two factions in the last 3 days, or if both factions have influence under 5%.

More info here: http://elite-dangerous.wikia.com/wiki/Influence#Civil_War